# Group dates by difference betwen rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to group some data using just one query that uses the dates between rows. Let me give an example:

**DATA**

```
IDE     DATE
------  ----------
AA1111  23-05-2016
AA1111  25-05-2016
AA1111  25-05-2016
AA1111  13-09-2016
AA1111  02-11-2016
AA1111  23-11-2016
AA1111  06-02-2017
AA1111  06-06-2017
AA1111  01-09-2017
AA1111  12-10-2017
AA1111  17-04-2018
AA1111  25-05-2018
AA1111  05-06-2018
```

I want to group the dates when the difference is less than 16 days. I already calculate the difference between the date and following date with:

```
SELECT  T.IDE, 
        T.DATE, 
        MAX(T.DATE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING ) - T.DATE AS DIF 

    FROM TESTPAT1 T ;
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
IDE     DATE        DIF
------  ----------  ---
AA1111  23-05-2016  2
AA1111  25-05-2016  0
AA1111  25-05-2016  111
AA1111  13-09-2016  50
AA1111  02-11-2016  21
AA1111  23-11-2016  75
AA1111  06-02-2017  120
AA1111  06-06-2017  87
AA1111  01-09-2017  41
AA1111  12-10-2017  187
AA1111  17-04-2018  38
AA1111  25-05-2018  11
AA1111  05-06-2018  0
```

From here, I could use the difference between rows, but the window of 16 days is my problem, since every date in a group must be inside this window starting from the first date of the window.

Some things to notice: The dates are sorted ascending and my expected output would be:

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
IDE     DATE        GROUP

AA1111  23-05-2016  1
AA1111  25-05-2016  1
AA1111  25-05-2016  1
AA1111  13-09-2016  2
AA1111  02-11-2016  3
AA1111  23-11-2016  4
AA1111  06-02-2017  5
AA1111  06-06-2017  6
AA1111  01-09-2017  7
AA1111  12-10-2017  8
AA1111  17-04-2018  9
AA1111  25-05-2018  10
AA1111  05-06-2018  10
```

**NOTE**: *THIS ARE NOT THE ACTUAL VARIABLE NAMES*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is known as a "bit fitting" problem.  In your case, you are trying to fit your data in to groups that can each hold up to 16 days' worth of data.

There are several well-known ways to use SQL to solve bin fitting problems.  `MATCH RECOGNIZE` is as good as any of them:

```
with test_data (IDE,     "DATE") AS (
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('23-05-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('25-05-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('25-05-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('13-09-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('02-11-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('23-11-2016','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('06-02-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('06-06-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('01-09-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('12-10-2017','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('17-04-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('25-05-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA1111',  TO_DATE('05-06-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL )
SELECT ide, "DATE", mno as "GROUP"
FROM test_data
match_recognize (
  partition by ide
  order by "DATE"
  measures 
    match_number() as mno,
    "DATE" - FIRST(GRP."DATE") as dif
    all rows per match
    pattern (  grp* )
    define 
      grp AS "DATE" - FIRST("DATE") < 16
  );
```

## Results

> ```
> +--------+-----------+-------+
> |  IDE   |   DATE    | GROUP |
> +--------+-----------+-------+
> | AA1111 | 23-MAY-16 |     1 |
> | AA1111 | 25-MAY-16 |     1 |
> | AA1111 | 25-MAY-16 |     1 |
> | AA1111 | 13-SEP-16 |     2 |
> | AA1111 | 02-NOV-16 |     3 |
> | AA1111 | 23-NOV-16 |     4 |
> | AA1111 | 06-FEB-17 |     5 |
> | AA1111 | 06-JUN-17 |     6 |
> | AA1111 | 01-SEP-17 |     7 |
> | AA1111 | 12-OCT-17 |     8 |
> | AA1111 | 17-APR-18 |     9 |
> | AA1111 | 25-MAY-18 |    10 |
> | AA1111 | 05-JUN-18 |    10 |
> +--------+-----------+-------+
> ```

#### Update for 11g users using `MODEL` clause

This query should work on 11g to solve your bin fitting problem.  Same results as above, just a different approach.

```
with 
  -- First, sort the input data because we need to be able to refer
  -- to the prior row and `lag` doesn't really work in `MODEL`, afaik.
sorted_inputs ( ide, sort_order, "DATE", first_date_in_group, grp, diff) as
( SELECT ide, 
         row_number() over ( partition by ide order by "DATE" ) sort_order, 
         "DATE", 
         -- These columns are place holders for the MODEL clause to update
         CAST(NULL AS DATE) first_date_in_group, 
         0 grp, 
         0 diff 
  FROM   test_data )
SELECT  ide, "DATE", grp "GROUP"
from    sorted_inputs
model 
partition by (ide)
dimension by (sort_order)
measures ( "DATE", grp, first_date_in_group, diff )
rules update automatic order
( grp[1] = 1,
  first_date_in_group[1] = "DATE"[1],
  diff[ANY] = "DATE"[CV()] - first_date_in_group[CV()-1],
  grp[sort_order>1] = grp[cv()-1] + CASE WHEN diff[CV()] > 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  first_date_in_group[sort_order>1] = CASE WHEN diff[CV()] > 16 THEN "DATE"[CV()] ELSE first_date_in_group[CV()-1] END
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It seems a good answer but Im using 11g so I can not use it.

Comment: You can also use MODEL clause.  I may update my answer to show that later if I have time.

Comment: @Rolandocq I updated my answer with an 11g-specific solution.

Comment: Wow thats actually what I needed, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the previous row.  See if the date difference is greater than or equal to 16 days.  If it is, it starts a new group.  The group identifier is then the sum of these "start group" values.

In SQL:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_date > date - interval '16' day then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by ide order by date) as grp
from (select t.*, 
             lag(date) over (partition by ide order by date) as prev_date
      from TESTPAT1 T
     ) t;
```

Note:  This assumes that you actually want separate groups for each `ide`.  If that is not the case, then remove the `partition by` clauses.

Comment: Thats pretty close, however if the date `'09-06-2016'` was in the data, it would be assigned the value of 1, and since `'23-05-2016'` is the first date of the window and the difference between them is 17, the date `'09-06-2016'` should be group 2

Comment: The problem is not comparing with the following row, but comparing with an unknown number of rows based on the date difference

Comment: @Rolandocq . . . I thought you wanted rolling periods, so if every day in January were in this data, then they would all be in the same group.

Comment: Its a complicated problem to explain since Im not an english speaker. If every day un January were in the data, then from 1-16 should be group 1, the rest should be group 2

Comment: @Rolandocq . . . I understand.  You need a recursive or hierarchical query in order to do this.  If you have a lot of data, it might not be very efficient.

Comment: The cases of what I explain are actually some few outliers so, Im going to approach the problem with this solution.